# Loop to create new variable based on answers to other variables

Tags: r, loops, recode

I would like to create a new variable based on the answers to three other variables (A,B and C) in my data set. Basically my variables have three modalities : "often", "sometime" and "never". I would like to have a new variable in which each individuals has a grade ranging from 0 to 3. For each variable (A,B and C), if he answers "often", he gets 1 point otherwise, he gets 0.

My data set looks like this with "often" coded with 2 ; "sometimes" coded with 1 and "never" coded with 0.

```
A <- c(2,1,1,NA, 0,2)
B <- c(2,2,0,1,2,NA)
C <- c(2,1,NA,2,1,0)

data <- data.frame(A,B,C)
```

I know I could use case_when but it is a rather unwieldy solution. I was thinking of a loop but I never used loops in R. Can you help me with this loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

*Update: thanks to markus. His solution (`rowSums(data == 2, na.rm = TRUE))`is much better than my original*

---

### base R

```
data$points = rowSums(data == 2, na.rm = TRUE)
```

---

### dplyr

```
library(dplyr)

data %>% mutate(point = rowSums(data == 2, na.rm = TRUE))
```

---

### data.table

```
library(data.table)

setDT(data)

data[, points:=rowSums(data == 2, na.rm = TRUE)]
```

---

**Output**

```
> data
   A  B  C points
1  2  2  2      3
2  1  2  1      1
3  1  0 NA      0
4 NA  1  2      1
5  0  2  1      1
6  2 NA  0      1
```

Comment: Yes exactly! And if I have other colums (let's say D and E) that i don't want to integrate in the row sum,  can I specify that I want to row sum only on A,B and C?

Comment: Yes, than you could specifiy the columns like `data$points = rowSums(data[c("A", "B", "C")] == 2, na.rm = TRUE)` or with column index `data$points = rowSums(data[c(1,2,3)] == 2, na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: Thank you for your help, i was able to create my variable!